# Parallel Step execution in spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

Right now I got to know that we can run concurrent steps in spring batch using Parallel Steps (http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/scalability.html 7.2).I did and got success with it.
But When I see the database what has happened is person record in the table is updated with others person information, though I have made my ItemProcessor as synchronized.
Background about what job is doing is simple, just process person records from person table across department (200,400) and writes in to a flat file. 
When I saw flat file I could see records a person from department 200 is written with person information from department 400.Kindly help is any thing i need to take care of?

```
<batch:job id="dept">
    <batch:step id="dojStep1" parent="dojMainStep1" next="parallelProcessMatch">
    </batch:step>
    <batch:split id="parallelProcessMatch" task-executor="taskExecutor">
        <batch:flow>
            <batch:step id="step200" parent="dojMainStep200" >
            </batch:step>
        </batch:flow>
        <batch:flow>
            <batch:step id="step400" parent="dojMainStep400" >
            </batch:step>
        </batch:flow>
    </batch:split>
</batch:job>

<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor"/>


<!-- Start parallelProcessMatch -->
<!-- Start dojMainStep200 -->
<batch:step id="dojMainStep200" abstract="true">
    <batch:tasklet>
        <batch:chunk commit-interval="1000" reader="dojDbReader200"
            processor="dojMatchItemProcessor200" writer="dojClassifierMatchReportWriter200">
            <batch:streams>
                <batch:stream ref="itemWriterMatch200" />
                <batch:stream ref="itemWriterUnMatch200" />
            </batch:streams>
        </batch:chunk>
    </batch:tasklet>
    <batch:listeners>
        <batch:listener ref="dojMatch200PageHeaderCallback" />
        <batch:listener ref="dojUnMatch200PageHeaderCallback" />
        <batch:listener ref="dojInPageFooterCallback" />
    </batch:listeners>
</batch:step>

<bean id="dojMatchItemProcessor200"
    class="com.batchinterface.dept.recordresultsvr.DojMatchItemProccesor"
    p:holdingTankDao-ref="holdingTankDao" p:rsdProvider-ref="rsdProvider" p:searchProvider-ref="searchProvider"  />

<bean id="dojDbReader200"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.StoredProcedureItemReader"
    p:dataSource-ref="oracleDataSource" p:rowMapper-ref="dojMatchRowMapper200"
    scope="step" p:function="false" p:procedureName="PKG_JOIN.PRC_SELECT"
    p:preparedStatementSetter-ref="dojmatchpropertySetter200"
    p:refCursorPosition="1">
    <property name="parameters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlOutParameter">
                <constructor-arg index="0" value="c1" />
                <constructor-arg index="1">
                    <util:constant static-field="oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.CURSOR" />
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter">
                <constructor-arg index="0" value="dept" />
                <constructor-arg index="1">
                    <util:constant static-field="oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.VARCHAR" />
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dojmatchpropertySetter200"
    class="com.batchinterface.dept.recordresultsvr.DojPreparedStateSetter">
    <property name="dept" value="200" />
</bean>

<bean id="dojMatchRowMapper200"
    class="com.batchinterface.dept.recordresultsvr.DojMatchRowMapper" />

<bean id="dojClassifierMatchReportWriter200"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.support.ClassifierCompositeItemWriter"
    p:classifier-ref="dojMatchClassifier200">
</bean>

<bean id="dojMatchClassifier200"
    class="com.batchinterface.dept.recordresultsvr.DojMatchReportClassifier"
    p:itemWriterMatch200-ref="itemWriterMatch200"
    p:itemWriterUnMatch200-ref="itemWriterUnMatch200"
    p:lastRunDate-ref="LastSuccessfulRunDate200">
</bean>
<!-- End dojMainStep200 -->
<!-- Start dojMainStep400 -->
<batch:step id="dojMainStep400" abstract="true">
    <batch:tasklet>
        <batch:chunk commit-interval="1000" reader="dojDbReader400"
            processor="dojMatchItemProcessor400" writer="dojClassifierMatchReportWriter400">
            <batch:streams>
                <batch:stream ref="itemWriterMatch400" />
                <batch:stream ref="itemWriterUnMatch400" />
            </batch:streams>
        </batch:chunk>
    </batch:tasklet>
    <batch:listeners>
        <batch:listener ref="dojMatch400PageHeaderCallback" />
        <batch:listener ref="dojUnMatch400PageHeaderCallback" />
        <batch:listener ref="dojInPageFooterCallback" />
    </batch:listeners>
</batch:step>

<bean id="dojMatchItemProcessor400"
    class="com.batchinterface.dept.recordresultsvr.DojMatchItemProccesor"
    p:holdingTankDao-ref="holdingTankDao" p:rsdProvider-ref="rsdProvider" p:searchProvider-ref="searchProvider"  />

<bean id="dojDbReader400"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.StoredProcedureItemReader"
    p:dataSource-ref="oracleDataSource" p:rowMapper-ref="dojMatchRowMapper400"
    scope="step" p:function="false" p:procedureName="PKG_JOIN.PRC_SELECT"
    p:preparedStatementSetter-ref="dojmatchpropertySetter400"
    p:refCursorPosition="1">
    <property name="parameters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlOutParameter">
                <constructor-arg index="0" value="c1" />
                <constructor-arg index="1">
                    <util:constant static-field="oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.CURSOR" />
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter">
                <constructor-arg index="0" value="dept" />
                <constructor-arg index="1">
                    <util:constant static-field="oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.VARCHAR" />
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dojmatchpropertySetter400"
    class="com.batchinterface.dept.recordresultsvr.DojPreparedStateSetter">
    <property name="dept" value="400" />
</bean>

<bean id="dojMatchRowMapper400"
    class="com.batchinterface.dept.recordresultsvr.DojMatchRowMapper" />

<bean id="dojClassifierMatchReportWriter400"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.support.ClassifierCompositeItemWriter"
    p:classifier-ref="dojMatchClassifier400">
</bean>

<bean id="dojMatchClassifier400"
    class="com.batchinterface.dept.recordresultsvr.DojMatchReportClassifier"
    p:itemWriterMatch400-ref="itemWriterMatch400"
    p:itemWriterUnMatch400-ref="itemWriterUnMatch400"
    p:lastRunDate-ref="LastSuccessfulRunDate400">
</bean>
<!-- End dojMainStep400 -->
<!-- End parallelProcessMatch -->
```

Comment: Does this work in single threaded mode?  My hunch is this isn't Spring Batch related and has something to do with the your code...

Comment: I didnt synchronized the dao class methods,after making synchronized dao class methods,its working fine.

/**
Making dao class methods as well process method of ItemProcessor as synchronized.
**/
private UpdateDAO dao;

@Override
public synchronized MatchOutObject process(MatchInObject obj) throws Exception 
{
dao.update(obj);<-- In the first time i didnt made them as synchronized,next I made them  like synchronized update(MatchInObject) in UpdateDAO .
...

}